# CodeIgniter - add data attributes on <options> using form_dropdown()

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

How can I add data attributes in the `<option>` tags using the `form_dropdown()` helper ? To generate something like this, for example:

```
// the part that I'm interested is the **data-code** attribute
<select class="form-control" name="country">
     <option value="a" data-code="code1">itemOne</option>
     <option value="b" data-code="code2">itemTwo</option>
     <option value="c" data-code="code3">itemThree</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I don't know it is possible or not. But I would do this way:

```
<?php if(sizeof($countries) > 0): ?>
<select class="form-control" name="country">
    <?php foreach($countries as $country): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $country['value'] ?>" data-code="<?php echo $country['code'] ?>"><?php echo $country['display'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where as, array of `$countries` should be as below:

```
$countries = array(
    array('value'=>'a','code'=>'code1','display'=>'itemOne'),
    array('value'=>'b','code'=>'code2','display'=>'itemTwo'),
    array('value'=>'c','code'=>'code3','display'=>'itemThree')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
    foreach($appertisers as $row ){
        $array[] = $row->product;
        $price[] = $row->price;
    }
    $array = array_merge(array('' => 'Please Select'), $array);
    echo form_dropdown('appetisers',  $array);
```

Dome something like that.